# How do client side decorations work with Gnome 3.10 and GTK 3?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gnome-3, window-decoration

As the title says, how would you go about converting a standard GTK3 application written in C (although Python should work as well with the `gobject` bindings) to have client-side decorations? I really like the idea, but I couldn't find anything that did this other than the default Gnome 3.10 apps (settings, tweak tool etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTK+ windows by default are decorated by the window manager. You can request the titlebar of an application be replaced in GTK+ 3.10 or higher by calling

```
gtk_window_set_titlebar(window, header);
```

where `header` is a `GtkHeaderBar` widget and `window` is the window you wish to have client side decorations. The official GNOME documentation has more information [on this subject](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-titlebar). As far as I gather the window manager is under no obligation to respect this request and can continue decorating it in the server.